# After I split a string how can I use the list that is created to then create a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file that has names put together that are related to each other, and I need the first set to a key, the second to a value, but when I run the program, I get the error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I have researched this, but, I haven't found a way to fix it. Below is the code, and a link to some of the material I found in trying to fix this issue.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2BwrdjlsW4

```
dataFile = open("names.dat", 'r')
myDict = {}
for line in dataFile:
    k,v = line.strip( ). split(",")
    myDict[k.strip (":")] = v.strip ( )
    print(k, v)
dataFile.close()
def findFather(myDict, lookUp):
    for key, value in myDict.items ( ):
        for v in value:
            if lookUp in value:
                return key
lookUp = raw_input ("Enter a son's name: ")
print "The father you are looking for is ",findFather(myDict, lookUp)
```

the file is saved as "names.dat" and is listed all on one line with the values:

```
john:fred, fred:bill, sam:tony, jim:william, william:mark, krager:holdyn, danny:brett, danny:issak, danny:jack, blasen:zade, david:dieter, adam:seth, seth:enos
```

Comment: `line.strip( ). split(",")` gives you a list of key, value pairs: `['john:fred ', 'fred:bill ', ...]`. Iterate over it, split each one again, and set the appropriate key in the dictionary.

Comment: You're probably getting that error on line 4, where `k` and `v` are 2 variables, but you're splitting that big line into like 15+ things. IMO change it to `{f : l for f,l in [name.split(':') for name in dataFile.read().split(', ')] }`

Comment: I changed the title to better describe what you are having problems with.  I would put up the answer but @Blender and @a p have both explained the problem.  If it is not clear - when you split the string you are getting a list of name:name.  That happens and you are assigning the labels k and v but there are a large number of name:name pairs (more than 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
line.strip( ). split(",")
```

returns a list like:

```
["jhon:fred", "fred:bill", "sam:tony", ...]
```

so, when you do

```
 k,v = line.strip( ). split(",")
```

you're trying to put all values of that list into `k` and `v` that are only two.

Try this code:

```
for line in dataFile:
    for pair in line.strip(). split(","):
        k,v = pair. split(":")
    myDict[k.strip (":")] = v.strip()
    print(k, v)
```

**NOTE:** The code above is just for remove the error you're getting. I do not guarantee that this code is going to do what you want to do. Also I've not idea about what are you trygin to du with the code:

```
myDict[k.strip (":")] = v.strip()
```

Comment: That worked fine. This is supposed to get a name from the user (i.e. fred) and return the key or value associated with it. In this case, if the user enters fred it will return john. I'm now having a problem where if I enter fred, it will return None instead of the key associated with the name.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Please, is the answer help you don't forget the upvote. ;)